# ng-disabled not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my modal popup code , I am trying to disable a button if a text box is empty or nothing is entered in it .

```
<div id="add_account_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalForAddAccount" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Add a new Account</h3>
        <form class=" " name="addAccountForm">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="control-label" style="display: inline">
                        Account Name
                        <span class="controls" style="display: inline;color:red;">*</span>
                    </label>

                    <div class="controls" style="display: inline">
                        <input type="text" class="input-large" ng-model="vm.addedAccount" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left:7px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary " ng-class="{'disabled':vm.addedAccount === ''}" ng-click="vm.submitAddAccount()">Submit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the submit button on modal popup load is not disabled.

I also tried :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary " ng-disabled="vm.addedAccount === ''" ng-click="vm.submitAddAccount()">Submit</button>
```

But that also did not work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

ng-click fires even if ng-disabled is true
use ng-submit with ng-disabled instead.

```
<form class=" " name="addAccountForm" ng-submit="vm.submitAddAccount()">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label" style="display: inline">
                    Account Name
                    <span class="controls" style="display: inline;color:red;">*</span>
                </label>

                <div class="controls" style="display: inline">
                    <input type="text" class="input-large" ng-model="vm.addedAccount" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-left:7px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " ng-disabled="vm.addedAccount === ''">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary " ng-disabled="!vm.addedAccount.length" ng-click="vm.submitAddAccount()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-disabled` works well: http://codepen.io/DaniloPolani/pen/wgOpPa

Maybe `vm.addedAccount` is not an empty string? Try with a console log to print `vm.addedaccount === ''` or inside the angular brackets.